# DeprecationWarning: AppURLopener style of invoking requests is deprecated

Tags: python, fancyurlopener

I wrote a program a while ago and it always was fine until I replaced my hard drive and had to reinstall everything.

This is the code segment I guess that can't work anymore due to depreciation

```
class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
  version = "Mozilla/5.0"
opener = AppURLopener()
```

I'm doing a google search request and I needed to use this because google blocks normal requests. I don't know how to replace this with anything to make it work again.

Comment: Why doesn't it work anymore? Deprecated means it still works, but it might go away in a future version, so you should update it.

Comment: Oh I guess there is something else wrong with it that I have to figure out. Weird

Comment: FYI, `FancyURLOpener` was deprecated since Python 3.3. So I guess you must have upgraded from an old version of Python. If you upgraded from Python 2.x, there are many incompatible changes that could be causing your problems.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with my program is different than I thought it was. This isn't causing the problem.